# Program that searches through text document not working

Tags: c++, loops, file, fstream, ifstream

I am working on a program that reads a text file and then searches for whatever the user input. If his input is found it prints out the rest of the data. For some reason it seems to only work for the first 2 names or so. I am also wondering if you guys have any tips for a beginner on how to manipulate the data (for example have someone search for a player and change the passing or touchdowns int) using commands I might understand. I want to learn how to do these things so I am looking for advice more so than actual code. 
Here is the search code:

```
void nameinator()
{
    string line;
    string player;
    players temp;
    players pl[10];
    int i = 0;
    ifstream file("players.txt");

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Type in the players name: ";
        cin >> player;
        for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            file >> pl[i].name;
            if (pl[i].name == player)
            {
                file >> pl[i].position >> pl[i].passing >> pl[i].recieve >> pl[i].rush >> pl[i].touchdowns >> pl[i].catches;
                cout << pl[i].name << " " << pl[i].position << " " << pl[i].passing
                    << " " << pl[i].recieve << " " << pl[i].rush << " " << pl[i].touchdowns << " " << pl[i].catches << " " <<  i << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == 10)
            cout << "Could not find player" << i;
        i = 0;
    }
    else
        cout << "ERROR, could not acces file";
    file.close();
}
```

and here is the code in context:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream> 
#include <iomanip>
#include <string> 
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

struct players
{
    string name;
    string position; 
    int passing;
    int recieve;
    int rush;
    int touchdowns;
    int catches;
};

void nameinator()
{
    string line;
    string player;
    players temp;
    players pl[10];
    int i = 0;
    ifstream file("players.txt");

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "Type in the players name: ";
        cin >> player;
        for ( i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            file >> pl[i].name;
            if (pl[i].name == player)
            {
                file >> pl[i].position >> pl[i].passing >> pl[i].recieve >> pl[i].rush >> pl[i].touchdowns >> pl[i].catches;
                cout << pl[i].name << " " << pl[i].position << " " << pl[i].passing
                    << " " << pl[i].recieve << " " << pl[i].rush << " " << pl[i].touchdowns << " " << pl[i].catches << " " <<  i << endl;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (i == 10)
            cout << "Could not find player" << i;
        i = 0;
    }
    else
        cout << "ERROR, could not acces file";
    file.close();
}

void printinator()
{
    ifstream file("players.txt");
    players pl[10];

    if (file.is_open())
    {
        cout << "\n";
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; ++i)
        {
            file >> pl[i].name >> pl[i].position >> pl[i].passing >> pl[i].recieve >> pl[i].rush >> pl[i].touchdowns >> pl[i].catches;
            cout << pl[i].name << " " << pl[i].position << " " << pl[i].passing
                << " " << pl[i].recieve << " " << pl[i].rush << " " << pl[i].touchdowns << " " << pl[i].catches << endl;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    else
        cout << "ERROR, could not acces file";
}

int touchinator()
{
    cout << "";
    return 0;
}

int catchinator()
{
    cout << "";
    return 0;
}

int passinator()
{
    cout << "";
    return 0;
}

int recievinator()
{
    cout << "";
    return 0;
}

int rushinator()
{
    cout << "";
    return 0;
}

void menu()
{
    cout << "\n\t\tWhat would you like to do to the file? : ";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t1 to print single players data";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t2 to print all data";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t3 to update player touchdowns";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t4 to update number of catches";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t5 to update passing yards";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t6 to update recieveing yards";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t7 to update players rushing yards";
    cout << "\n\t\t\t99 to exit: ";
}

int main()
{
    int choice = 0;
    while (choice != 99)
    {
        menu();
        cin >> choice;
        switch (choice)
        {
        case 1:
            nameinator();
            break;
        case 2:
            printinator();
            break;
        case 3:
            touchinator();
            break;
        case 4:
            catchinator();
            break;
        case 5:
            passinator();
            break;
        case 6:
            recievinator();
            break;
        case 7:
            rushinator();
            break;
        case 99:
            exit(1);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

as well as the txt document

```
Bill Quarter_Back 70 0 8754 0 573
Jackson Receiver 55 87 50 5490 574
Grahm Running_Back 45 30 0 50 2800
McCoy Full_Back 25 10 0 25 3762
Daryl Quarter_Back 50 2 7560 0 450
Santiago Left_Tackle 5 0 0 0 0
Hanks Receiver 35 37 0 3590 876
Johnson Running_Back 25 80 0 100 4000
Miller Receiver 110 250 150 7867 2100
Ruth Quarter_Back 85 0 12901 0 3249
```

Comment: You are not discarding the rest of the line if the name does not match, so the number next to the first name will be read as the second name, and so on.

Comment: How do I discard the line?

Comment: You can place the line `file >> pl[i].position >> pl[i].passing >> pl[i].recieve >> pl[i].rush >> pl[i].touchdowns >> pl[i].catches;` before the `if` statement.

Comment: Wow, Ok I did that and it works, thank you, do you have any advice about how to manipulate the data? Like changing the touchdowns in?